# Fixed_order makes entry not display

Tags: matrix, playa

I found this [question and answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Q5R3.png) that has helped me to get where I currently am. My setup is very very similar to the setup discussed in this thread.

**HUGE UPDATE / EDIT**

I deleted pretty much my entire first post just to let everyone know.

Now I have a fresh install of EE and the modules below, and am working locally on MAMP.

- EE - 2.6 ( had no install issues!)
- Matrix - 2.5.4
- Assets - 2.1.2
- Playa - 4.4.2
- Wygwam - 2.7.1
- Better Work Flow - 1.6 (not being used to manage these pages yet)
- MAMP PHP - 5.3.6
- MySQL: 5.5.9
  Please note that I do not have Structure installed this time around. I also removed the Structure Tag related to this issue.

I have simplified my template as much as I could which is below.

```
{embed="includes/_html_header"} <!-- includes opening body tag -->
<div class="container">
    {exp:channel:entries channel="schedule" disable="categories|member_data|pagination"}
        <h1>{title}</h1>
        {schedule_rooms_day_1}
            {cell_1} - {cell_2} - {cell_3}
        {/schedule_rooms_day_1}
        <br/>
        <br/>
        {schedule_day_1}
            {cell_1}
                Session Name = {session_name}<br/>
                Session Speaker Child ID - {session_speaker:child_ids} (these are pulling in correct IDs, yippie!) <br/>
                Need to embed information below here about speaker of session<br/>
                {embed="includes/_speakers_import" entry_ids="{session_speaker:child_ids}"}<br/>
                <hr>
            {/cell_1}
        {/schedule_day_1}

    {/exp:channel:entries}
</div>
```

{embed="includes/_js"}
{embed="includes/_close_page"}

I have "{session_speaker:child_ids}" to help show me which entries should be pulled in. This is pulling in the correct information, same with my embed variable below.

Here is my embed template.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="sessions" dynamic="no" fixed_order="{embed:entry_ids}"}
{session_speaker}
    Embed value from embed - {embed:entry_ids} (these are still displaying correct info) <br/>
    Speaker Name - {speaker_name}<br/>
{/session_speaker}
```

{/exp:channel:entries}

Please note my issue still remains the same as before, if I include the fixed_order param no information shows up. If I try to do something like fixed_order="2|3|6|4" nothing is displayed. Same with entry_id.
If I remove fixed_order all my speakers show up, and my embed variable displays the correct entry id, which is a good thing.

On an other site I was trying to pull an embed variable into a param and was not able to get my information to display properly. I am wondering if there is a setting I have not turned on that might be effecting my templates.

With my clean install there were a few issues that showed up in my developers log which can be seen in the [linked image](http://johnhoysa.com/images/Developer_Log.png). Please note there is an error with Structure and Playa.

For Lisa I hope that my updated information is more helpful, as well as the developers log!

Travis, I appreciate the help and with the removal of Structure from the mix feel free to move forward and help others with Structure related issues!

Again, I appreciate the help and hopefully we can figure this out together!

Comment: When i do include fixed_order parameter I have it like so - fixed_order="0|{embed:entry_ids}". Also tried fixed_order="{embed:entry_ids}"

Comment: John, can you try this temporarily with hard-coding the ID? ie: fixed_order="1"? I'd like to rule out the embed. I'd recommend testing on an otherwise blank template.  Thank you!

Comment: I have tried hard coding the entries like so fixed_order="17175|17178|".

Comment: Also my main template is rather barren it pulls in two other embeds, my navigtaion and my footer which help open and close the page and that is it.

Comment: John - you're on EE 2.5.2 which is quite old; I need to ask you to upgrade to at least 2.5.5 to test this out.  2.6 is possibly better if you're going to take the time.  But I think you may be running into a problem that will be fixed with those upgrades.  But also - is the code you posted 100% of the template? That string is a template marker that didn't get replaced in parsing, so reducing is important here to figure out what's going on

Comment: Working on updating now. Will get back to you tomorrow. Got some weird PHP error due to DST I think.

Comment: Make sure your PHP date/time is set in PHP.ini. :)

Comment: Hi Lisa, I have tried updating to 2.5.5 and 2.6 and no luck on getting the information to show up as expected. I also have a few other issues with the upgrade process and also some module compatibility issues with 2.6. I appreciate the quick replies and suggestions! From here I am going to try something different, what I have no idea.

Comment: John, if you output the {title} for the channel entries  tag - do you get the right title back? I'd like to make sure that we're getting the right data from EE before looking to Playa.

Comment: Yess I get the right title! I also get the correct entry_id to pull up as well. I am thinking my template is bad and moving on to an other part of the site for now. I will keep you posted if I figure it out. Still not able to update EE to the latest version correctly and am looking into that more next week.

Comment: John - if you suspect it's your overall template, my recommendation is to start with minimum code and build up until you find the break point. Or reverse - start removing stuff.  Reduction and isolation are key. :)

Comment: Lisa please see updated information above. Clean install and still having issues. Not sure what I am missing!

Comment: John, what version of PHP are you on? We saw some errors with those decode JSON on PHP versions prior to 5.2 and do have a fix for it.  If you can email support@pixelandtonic.com we can get that to you. Please reference this thread.  Thank you!

Comment: And hold on, do you have a channel entries tag inside a channel entries tag?  Which one gives you the proper titles?  That's not a great optimization choice, so you are aware....

Comment: Hi Lisa, MAMP PHP is 5.3.6 and MySQL is version 5.5.9. Yeah I hear you about the tag and I am wondering what is up with that as well. I looked at the old docs - http://web.archive.org/web/20130314113550/http://pixelandtonic.com/playa/docs/nested-relationships - and this is how it says to set up the embed as well. Is there a better method? Also I figured out a work around that I have implimented that might actually be a better solution for what I am trying to do. However, after all this time I just want to see the current system working.

Comment: John - are you able to get fixed order working for you on any channel entries tag, on its own?

Comment: Yes I am able to sort by fixed order. I am testing this on my clean install. fixed_order="12|14|10".

Comment: John, is Super Admin access available to this site?  I think it would help for me to look at it directly.

Comment: Unfortunately access is not possible. Should I send you a copy of my database? Its a simple site so what I might do is push it to my own server to allow you access to it if worse comes to worse. Let me know what is best for you.

Comment: Getting this on a server where I can troubleshoot would be a great help, John.  There's a chance I'll need to work with one of my devs for help, as well as ask you to look at something/check something.  So a shared environment is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where this fixed_order parameter is. Does it work if it's not in an embed and straight in the page?

Comment: I currently removed the fixed_order parameter in the example. if I remove the embed and simply put my code straight into the main template the information does not display properly. For example this is what I get: Speaker Name = {playazvj5FRQp:speaker_name}
{/exp:playa:children}